# Memcached: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file

Tags: tomcat7, memcached, libevent, spymemcached

**Situation**: I installed memcached on a CenTOS 5 (64 bit). I also ended up installing some PHP plugins using PECL, though they're unnecessary now.

**Problem**:When I execute

```
/etc/init.d/memcached start
```

I get the following error:

```
Starting memcached: memcached: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But the file libevent-2.0.so.5 is present in /opt/couchbase/lib/.

Should it be there in some other folder ? How to get memcached to start ?

Answer (score 3):

/opt/couchbase/lib will not be set on your system library path by default. That's why your unable to find libevent when running /etc/init.d/memcached.

To quickly solve this you can just run the command as follows:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/couchbase/lib /etc/init.d/memcached

or to solve this over the long term add the following file (assuming your using centos):

/etc/ld.so.conf.d/couchbase.conf

and in that file add the path "/opt/couchbase/lib". Then run ldconfig and re-run the command to start memcached.

Answer (score 1):

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libevent-2.1.so.6  /usr/lib64/libevent-2.1.so.6

for libevent-2.0.so.5 the same.